# tmux pin to avoid scrolling

Tags: linux, tmux

Often when I run a command that writes to stdout, and that command fails, I have to scroll up (using uncomfortable key-bindings) looking for the place where I pressed Enter, to see what the first error was (out of hundreds others, across many screens of text). This is both annoying and time-consuming. I wish there was a feature which allowed me to pin my current terminal to the place where I am now, then start the command, see only the first lines of the output (as many as fits below my cursor) and let the rest of the output be written but not displayed. In other words I would like a feature to allow me automatically scroll up to the place where I gave the command, to see the first lines of the output (where usually the origin of the failure is displayed).

I searched for it but I didn't find it. Do you know if such feature exists? Or have an idea how to implement it with some tricks or workarounds?

Comment: No. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a unique shell prompt you could bind a key to jump between shell prompts, for example something like this will make `C-b S` jump to the previous shell prompt then `S` subsequent ones:

```
bind S copy-mode \; send -X search-backward 'nicholas@myhost:'
bind -Tcopy-mode S send -X search-backward 'nicholas@myhost:'
```

Or similarly you could search for error strings if they have a recognisable prefix. If you install the tmux 3.1 release candidate, you can search for regular expressions.

Alternatively, you could use `capture-pane` to load the entire history into an editor with key bindings you prefer, for example:

```
$ tmux capturep -S- -E- -p|vim -
```

Or pipe to `grep` or whatever. Note you will need to use a temporary file for this to work with emacs.

Or try to get into the habit of `tee`ing commands with lots of output to a file to start with.

Comment: Hm... I am using zsh theme with minimal prompt (I don't like complex themes). And my tmux version is 2.6. Yes, I know I can pipe this to less, tee or vim, but that is so uncomfortable. Seems like none of these helps much...

Comment: Only workaround I see is to prepend my command with some "echo myname &&" and then search backwards. But that is also not great.

Comment: There is no magic way to do this, you will need to put something recognisable in your prompt or write helper scripts or aliases to either print a marker or make loading into an editor more comfortable for you. Some terminals like iTerm2 have a way to invisibly mark a prompt by embedding escape sequences in it, but tmux does not support this, although I'm not opposed to having it if someone writes it :-).

Comment: Maybe I will create a pull request for this :-)